# Need to sum ata up but can only count

Tags: awk

I have the flu but this is no excuse. I am going crazy over this (I'm sure the solution is simple). I got this input file

```
491 Reynosa
639 JGS-Memphis
  5 JGS-Memphis
480 Reynosa
247 JGS-Memphis
556 Reynosa
 71 JGS-Memphis
993 Reynosa
  5 JGS-Memphis
773 Reynosa
 63 JGS-Memphis
589 Reynosa
809 Reynosa
671 Reynosa
397 Reynosa
402 Reynosa
160 Reynosa
612 Reynosa
658 Reynosa
549 Reynosa
691 Reynosa
782 Reynosa
579 Reynosa
```

I need to do a tally but my code...

```
    awk -F" " '{counts[$2]=counts[$2]+1}    END     {for (key in counts)         
printf "%s\t%d\n", key, counts[key]}    ' inputfile.txt
```

is counting instead of summing...

```
JGS-Memphis 6
Reynosa 17
```

I want do something like this

```
JGS-Memphis 1030
Reynosa ...
```

what am I missing here??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F" " '{counts[$2]=counts[$2]+$1} 
    END {for (key in counts) printf "%s\t%d\n", key, counts[key]}    ' inputfile.txt
```

You were missing a "$".